# How to check Sql queries are in correct naming conventions using hive/MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, hiveql

How to check whether Sql is following correct naming conventions in hive/ MapReduce / pig?

For example:

```
select * FROM emp WHERE empid = 101;
```

Once checked, the output must be in the following format:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE empid = 101;
```

Anyone who knows,   please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you clear the question. ? What are you trying to say?

Comment: Are you looking for a parser to analyse the query?